# error opening trace file: No such file in directory (2), cannot locate file

Tags: java, android, file-io, inputstream, trace

I am new here. 
I consider myself to have broken past newbie-ism and I am breaking into intermediate programming. I am trying to read from my assets folder, and the problem I am having is that my program keeps catching the exception. Can you help me figure out what I am doing wrong? Here is my code:

```
    package com.example.testone;

    import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.res.AssetManager;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class AssetsTest extends Activity {

    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    setContentView(textView);

    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
    InputStream inputStream = null;

    try {
        inputStream = getAssets().open("myawesometext.txt");
        String text = loadTextFile(inputStream);
        textView.setText(text);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        textView.setText("Couldn't load file");
    } finally {
        if (inputStream != null)
            try {
                inputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                textView.setText("Couldn't close file");
            }
    }
}



public String loadTextFile(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] bytes = new byte[4096];
    int len = 0;
    while ((len = inputStream.read(bytes)) > 0)
        byteStream.write(bytes, 0, len);
    return new String(byteStream.toByteArray(), "UTF8");
}
```

}

I have searched every website including this one, combing over the other similar questions, and could not find an answer that worked for me. Your help would be so greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could try e.getMessage(), it should help you more :)

Comment: Okay thanks! I will try that. I moved on to different things, yet I never figured this problem out. I will give it a shot.

Comment: Did you solved this?